# Remove duplicate and checked elements of array

Tags: arrays, angular, checkbox, duplicates

I have users and each of them can have some company role. I created popup modal that get all company roles in list with checkboxes. For every role that that user have at that moment, role is checked in list. When uncheck role and submit, I want that list to update with .put method.

Problem is that I made function, but that function is making double roles whenever I leave any of previous roles still checked. Seems that they get in array in way that function see them as checked or something like that.

My ts:

```
export class AddRolePopupComponent extends PopupAbstract<any> implements OnInit {

userRoles = [];
userRolesNames = [];
selectedRoles = [];


constructor( private userService: UserService, private companyService: CompanyService, public dialog: DialogRef<any> ) {

    super( dialog, dialog.context );
}

ngOnInit() {        
    this.userService.getRolesForUser(this.context.id).subscribe(
        response => { this.handleSucess( response ); },
        error => { console.error( error ); },
    );
    }


handleSucess(response) {
        this.userRoles = response;
        this.userRolesNames = response.map(userRole => userRole.name);
}

selectRole(category, event , role) {
    var index = this.userRoles.indexOf(role);
    if (event.target.checked) {
        this.userRoles.push(role);
     } else {
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.userRoles.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

}

submitRole(){
    console.log(this.userRoles);
}
```

userRoles = response on handleSucess is getting me all roles that selected user currently have.

html:

```
<div class="roles-div">
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <label class="label-roles">Select User Roles</label>
</div>
<form #rolesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitRole(rolesForm)" >
<div class="flex-column-center">
    <div class="flex-center width90 height300 checkbox-div">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let role of context.roles">
                    <input class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [checked]="userRolesNames.indexOf(role.name)>-1"  name="role"  (change)="selectRole(option, $event, role)">{{ role.label }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column-center2 width35">
        <button class="btn-main10" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to verify if the `role` is exist already in the list before push it in the array :

```
selectRole(category, event , role) {
    var index = this.userRoles.indexOf(role);
    // i added index == -1 : 
    if (event.target.checked && index == -1) {
        this.userRoles.push(role);
    } else {
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.userRoles.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    // map again the new userroles : 
    this.userRolesNames = userRoles.map(userRole => userRole.name);
}
```

Comment: Tried to change with your answer ...I have 2 roles on user ...Company Administrator and Project Manager ...if I uncheck Project Manager and submit ... i stil get double that ...and then shows me Project Manager, Company Administrator, Project Manager, Company Administrator...

Comment: i think you have to map again the  `userRoles` to names `this.userRolesNames = userRoles.map(userRole => userRole.name);` , i edited the answer

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: I still uncheck one role, but it remains the same ...no change

Comment: try to log the `event.target.checked` whenever the method is called to see what is happening exactly when you uncheck the role

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with your selectRole function.

The order is not right.

If: checked
If: exists, remove it
Else: push it

```
selectRole(category, event, role) {
    var index = this.userRoles.indexOf(role);

    if (event.target.checked) {

        if (index > -1) {
            this.userRoles.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            this.userRoles.push(role);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it ...tried this but still not what is suposed to do ...perhaps this should be in different order or different way totaly...

Comment: Create a small stackblitz to help debug the issue

Comment: dificult ...I have services related, abstract components ... Have no idea how to make it functional... sorry ...but thanks for help :)